# jq '.[]' doesnt give jsonObjects but rather give psobjects in powershell. How to solve this?

Tags: json, powershell, jq

Taking an example from JQs official site, I am trying to parse the jsonArray in below example screenshot.

[image: Parsing Json Array using jq]

I am trying to get both jsonObjects, so that I can do something with them for my problem statement. However, when I try to do this in PowerShell using below code:

$inputJson = '[{"name":"JSON", "good":true}, {"name":"XML", "good":false}]'

$items = $inputJson |   jq '.[]'

I get not two $items objects but 8 $items psobjects. As seen in the second screenshot. 
[image]

Any pointers, on what changes I can make to get only two jsonObjects here?

Comment: That's just 8 strings

Comment: It seems like it's working?  .[0] gives the first one and .[1] gives the second one.

Comment: .[0] gives { . My intention is to grab the whole JSON object. So in the above example, a way to get only two objects  to contain JSON objects (not 8 strings)

Comment: This is in powershell?  It works for me.  If you save it to a variable, all jq does is output strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is confusing.  All jq does is output strings.  Powershell will make each line a new string array element.  The only way I see it doing what you want, is with jq's `--compact-output` option, which outputs one object (to jq) per line.  That seems to be the way that online example was run, anyway.  But to powershell, these are two *strings*.  They would be objects to powershell only after using `convertfrom-json`.

```
$items = $inputJson | jq '.[]' --compact-output
$items

{"name":"JSON","good":true}
{"name":"XML","good":false}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This indeed gives me what I was looking for. This gives me now two ways to get jsonItems from Array.

Comment: Just a minor addition to your last remark about ... "But to powershell, these are two strings. They would be objects to powershell only after using convertfrom-json."  As I understood, everything in PowerShell is an Object. So they are already objects with your above code (without using convertfrom-json). Thats just a minor observation though.

Answer (score 1):

Although still dont know how to do it with jq, here is another way of achieving what I wanted using Powershell.

```
$inputJson = '[{"name":"JSON", "good":true}, {"name":"XML", "good":false}]' | ConvertFrom-Json
write-host "`nNr of jsonObjects:"
write-host $inputJson.Length

write-host "`nfirst jsonObject:"
Write-Host $inputJson[0]

write-host "`njsonObjects value:"
$value = $inputJson[0] | ConvertTo-Json
Write-Host $value
```

Result is:
Nr of jsonObjects:
2

first jsonObject:
@{name=JSON; good=True}

jsonObjects value:
{
    "name":  "JSON",
    "good":  true
}

Comment: I would still appreciate it if someone can post an alternate answer using jq.